# Is there any way whatsoever of 'converting' a char array to a char* array in C?

Tags: c

Im just curious if there is anyway of directly converting a char array to a char* array such as:

```
char charArray[5]={'h','e','l','l','o'};
```

'Converted' to:

```
char *pointerArray[5]={"h","e","l","l","o"};
```

Comment: Nothing built in, but you can do it easily with a loop.

Comment: Note that your second array points to null-terminated strings, but the chars in the first array don't have null terminators. So you'll need to allocate 2-byte arrays for each one so you can copy the character and add the terminator.

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Comment: In the first case the entire data structure occupies 5 bytes. In the second case, not only do you need at least 10 bytes for the text, you need a place to store the five pointers. On a machine with 4-byte pointers that's another 20 bytes; on a machine with 8-byte pointers that's another 40 bytes.

Comment: char *charPointerArray = "hello"; // That's all
Technically an array is a pointer too. So there is nothing to convert. Both the array and pointer just hold the memory address where the character array begins. You can convert an array to a pointer simply by assigning as well:
char array[] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
char *pArray = array; // Here now you have the memory address in pArray variable.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **convert_array(char *arr_in, size_t arr_in_sz)
{
  char **arr_out = (char **)malloc(arr_in_sz * sizeof(char *));

  for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_in_sz; ++i) {
    arr_out[i] = (char *)malloc(2);
    arr_out[i][0] = arr_in[i];
    arr_out[i][1] = '\0';
  }

  return arr_out;
}

void free_array(char **arr, size_t arr_sz)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_sz; ++i)
    free(arr[i]);
  free(arr);
}

int main()
{
  char array_char[] = {'h', 'i'};

  char **array_str = convert_array(array_char, sizeof(array_char));

  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array_char); ++i)
    printf("%s\n", array_str[i]);

  free_array(array_str, sizeof(array_char));
}
```

Comment: In principle, `malloc` could fail, and your code don't test against that.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a place to store the string literals. You need twice as much memory as for the `charArray` - to store letters and zero terminating characters, one zero for each letter - twice as much memory. Then initialize `pointerarray` to point to every second character inside memory. Like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char chararray[5]={'h','e','l','l','o'};

    char memory[sizeof(chararray) * 2];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(chararray); ++i) {
        memory[i * 2] = chararray[i];
        memory[i * 2 + 1] = '\0';
    }

    char *pointerarray[5];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(chararray); ++i) {
        // this loop could me merged with above loop
        pointerarray[i] = &memory[i * 2];
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", pointerarray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is one dimensional array and secon one is two dimensional. So if you just use pointer like that :
char *pointerArray it means you have an array but you can not assign like in the first example.